# GridView how to set a boundfield

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hi say I have a Gridview in which I want to display info about people. One BoundField may look like:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Age"
         HeaderText="Age" />
```

For a simple property of the Person object this is fine. However what about a property that is more complicated. Say the person object has a property called NameId. The Names object contains first and last names. To display a name I tried:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name.First" HeaderText="First Name" />
```

However this didn't work. Could someone please suggest how you could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer being to use a templatefield